# Two sideways figures on same page with two captions

Tags: floats, captions, rotating, floatrow

I have two figures that need to be in landscape mode. I am using the `rotating` package for that. Right now, they are automatically going to separate pages even though they could both fit on the same one (which is what I want). If I use [H] [H!], they still go to separate pages.

I tried nesting the two figures into the same `\beginfigure{sidewaysfigure}`, but then I get the **Error: Caption lost**. This is because I am using the `floatrow` package (which I am using in order to get the captions to appear over tables in my document instead of below). If I use `\RawFloats`, the images are no longer in landscape but in portrait (although the two captions are there now). If I delete `\usepackage{floatrow}` then all my tables get messed up in the other part of the document.

How do I get both figures to show up on the same page with both captions present while using `floatrow`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=top, labelformat=simple, font=large}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=1000pt}
\usepackage{rotating}

        \begin{sidewaysfigure}%\RawFloats
          \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=2.4in]{fig1}
            \caption{Caption1.}
          \label{Fig1}
            \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=1.5in]{fig2}
            \caption{Caption2.}
          \label{Fig2}
        \end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
qqqqqqq
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \hfill
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{Caption1}
      \label{fig:First}
    \end{minipage}
  }\hfill
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{Caption2}
      \label{fig:First}
    \end{minipage}
  }\hfill\strut
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am still getting an Error: Captions lost due to the floatrow.

Comment: Oh, but if I add `\RawFloats` after `\begin{figure}[htb]` then it works. Thank you!